# Is it possible to add a internal menu?

Tags: content-management-system, dotcms

I am pretty new using dotCMS and am thinking to buy a licence for enterprise edition. My question is, there is any chance to add a menu on the backend? Should I write a plugin for that? is there an easy way? 
I was able to add a menu with tools but actually I really need is to add links to content types by User/Role.

Thanks!
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWTxZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add your own "tools" on the back-end (called portlets from the developer perspective) by creating a dynamic (OSGi) plugin.  You can find example code for a portlet plugin in the dotCMS Github plugins repo:

https://github.com/dotCMS/plugin-seeds/tree/master/OSGi/com.dotcms.portlet

And the documentation on creating and adding OSGi plugins to dotCMS can be found here:

https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/osgi-plugins